# Красивый url не работает

Tags: .htaccess, php, mod_rewrite

Итак, начну с того, что есть такой htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# Если не файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# Если не директория
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Запускаем index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Есть также особая функция, которая преобразует url, get. Она сразу запускается:

```
function rewrite()
{
    $uri=preg_replace('#[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$#i', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $get_reqs=explode('/', $uri, 20);

    for($i=0; $i(знак меньше)sizeof($get_reqs);$i++)
    {
        if($get_reqs[$i]=='' && ($i+1)==sizeof($get_reqs))
            break;

        $_GET['value'.($i-1)]=$get_reqs[$i];    
    }
}
rewrite();
```

Если мы сделаем

```
print_r($_GET)
```

то вот что получим в ответ:

> Array ( [value-1] => [value0] => auth
> ) // на странице авторизации

и

> Array ( [value-1] => [value0] => reg )
> // на странице регистрации

И всё работает прекрасно. Страницы и url отображаются корректно. Обратите внимание на адресную строку скриншотов.
Пример №1:
[link text](http://savepic.su/5092860.jpg)

Пример №2:
[link text](http://savepic.su/5083647.jpg)

Но стоит мне перейти на адрес `http://multytasker.ru/help/new` , как сразу же сбиваются стили и исчезают картинки:
[link text](http://savepic.su/5063166.jpg)

Я даже не знаю, как это исправить. Может вы заметите что-нибудь? Заранее, спасибо.

Всё, дошло, где кнопка.

Сейчас, благодаря функции rewrite(), описанной выше, и htaccess у меня все ссылки по типу http://domain.ru/параметр. То есть у меня вообще нет ссылок, типа http://domain.ru/index.php?p=параметр. Но если Вы предложите выход с помощью index.php?p=index, то я тогда переделаю всё, что нужно.

1. перешел на http://multytasker.ru/index.php?p=payment
2. убрал функцию по преобразованию $_GET
3. заменил $p=$value0 на $p=$_GET['p']
4. в хтакесе только кодировка и Ваш код
5. Обновил страницу
6. Url не rewrite'нулся... По прежнему http://multytasker.ru/index.php?p=payment

Я что-то сделал не так?

```
htaccess  
========  
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8  
Options +FollowSymlinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1  
========
```

И всё... А в индексе - $p = $_GET['p']

Ссылка на скриншот http://cs625429.vk.me/v625429999/1c06d/90Ve3TvMVnc.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, ты используешь на странице относительные пути к стилям и картинкам, поэтому на них приходит не тот запрос, который ты ожидаешь. Рекомендую поменять пути на абсолютные.